# Dúvida em como imprimir datagridview em reportviewer

Tags: c#, sql-server

Preciso imprimir os dados de um DataGridViewer, o qual fica os produtos lançados na venda.
Qual a melhor forma de imprimir essas informações no Report?
Tentei usar o componente Table, porém não consigo passar as informações para ele, visto que ele precisa ser vinculado a um DataSet.

Uma observação é que tenho alguns textbox no report.rldc que já consegui preencher utilizando parâmetros, porém agora para imprimir as informações de um DataGrid acabei agarrando.

---

Eis o construtuor do form onde se encontra o report:

```
    public frmTesteImpressaoVenda(String nomeEmpresa, String enderecoEmpresa, String cnpjEmpresa, String telefoneEmpresa,
        String nomeCliente, String cpjCliente, DateTime DataVenda, String Pagamento) {

        InitializeComponent();
        reportVenda.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "GUI.ImpressaoVenda.rdlc";

        ReportParameter[] parms = new ReportParameter[8];
        parms[0] = new ReportParameter("NomeEmpresa", nomeEmpresa);
        parms[1] = new ReportParameter("EnderecoEmpresa", enderecoEmpresa);
        parms[2] = new ReportParameter("CnpjEmpresa", cnpjEmpresa);
        parms[3] = new ReportParameter("Telefone", telefoneEmpresa);
        parms[4] = new ReportParameter("Cliente", nomeCliente);
        parms[5] = new ReportParameter("Cpf", cpjCliente);
        parms[6] = new ReportParameter("DataVenda", DataVenda.ToString());
        parms[7] = new ReportParameter("Pagamento", Pagamento);

        reportVenda.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);
        reportVenda.LocalReport.Refresh();
        reportVenda.RefreshReport();

    }
```

O código abaixo é do form de venda onde passa os parametros para preenchimento do report.

```
    private void btImprimirTeste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        frmTesteImpressaoVenda impVenda = new frmTesteImpressaoVenda(
            CadastroEmpresa.nome_empresa,
            CadastroEmpresa.endereco + ", " + CadastroEmpresa.numendereco + " - " + CadastroEmpresa.bairro + " - " + CadastroEmpresa.cidade,
            CadastroEmpresa.cnpj,
            CadastroEmpresa.telefone,
            txtNomeCliente.Text,
            lbCpf.Text,
            DateTime.Now,
            cbTipoPagto.Text
        );

        impVenda.Show();

    }
```

Comment: o que você tem feito, poderia posta?

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Para utilizar a Table no Report é relativamente simples. Você poderá criar um DataSet Tipado e adicioná-lo em seu Report.

- Exibir painel de "Report Data" - View -> Report Data
- Clicar com o botão direto do mouse em "DataSets" e em "Add Dataset..."

Desta forma você poderá vincular um Objeto para ser o modelo do seu data set ou até mesmo o DataSet Tipado se esta for a sua opção.

Através do wizard você consegue, facilmente, adicionar um DataSource para o seu Report.

Ao inserir a Table em seu report(através da Toolbox), você poderá adicionar as colunas e fazer o bind dessas a uma propriedade do seu DataSource.

É importante lembrar que a Table possui uma propriedade "DataSetName", que define o nome do dataset que irá ser exibido na table. Essa propriedade é importante para que você possa "setar" o dataset em seu ReportDataSource através do código:

```
 ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1");
 rds.Value = repositorio.GetData();
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
```

Aqui um exemplo com o DataSet tipado: [Exemplo](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Report-Viewer-control-Tutorial-with-example.aspx)